# In React Router V4, how to navigate to a page outside defined basename?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4

Consider the following React Router V4 code:

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    let hasToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if (hasToken) return true;
    return false;
};

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated()
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : window.location = "/auth/login" } <<-- ERROR HERE
    />;

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/editor">
                <Switch>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={AppHome} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />

                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

`auth/login` is another ReactJs application that needs to be loaded from the server, or in other words, `auth/login` needs to bypass client routing and sent to server, where it will be routed and will serve a new ReactJS application (`auth` application with `login` page).

When trying to redirect (not authenticated) I´m getting the following error on browser console:

```
You are attempting to use a basename on a page whose URL path does not begin with a basename. 
Expected path "/login" to begin with "/editor"
```

Looks like I´m "trapped" inside React Router V4 and nothing can get out of the basename.

How can I solve that and redirect to a server page, quitting or bypassing the react router itself ?

Comment: Did you see: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/452 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Redirect` component provided by `react-router-dom`

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated()? <Component {...props} />
       : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: 'auth/login' }}
           />
       )
     }
   />
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/good-old-react-authentication-flow/src/containers/PrivateRoute)

Comment: Does not work for me. You stripped the `BrowserRouter` with the `basename` that is the main issue.

Comment: Well I tried in the app that goes with the example and it's working with a basename and it's working.

Comment: Doesnt work, where is the basename in your implementation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to install react-router-dom in your app

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

or

```
npm i -S react-router-dom
```

And import this

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Where you want to redirect

```
browserHistory.push('/path/some/where');
```

**your code should be**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const isAuthenticated = () => {
    let hasToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if (hasToken) return true;
    return false;
};

    const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, history }) =>
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                isAuthenticated()
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : history.push("/auth/login")}
        />;
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/editor">
                <Switch>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={AppHome} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:module"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />

                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: No. Changing `window.location` to `history.push` is not a solution. Better read again the problem...